# Building a matrix using two for loops. (How to save time without the loops)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, vectorization

I am using a function to build a matrix, call the matrix M. The components are distances between points i.e Mij=d(xi,xj), where this particular distance function is  D inverse times (xi-xj) dot product with (xi-xj). D is some matrix. I use the capital letter X to be the numpy array containing all the xi.

I have built the matrix using the following function but it required me to use **two for loops!**

```
def matrix(X,D):
    l=len(X)
    M=np.zeros(l**2)
    
    k=0 # set counter for indexing matrix
    
    for i in range(0,l):
        for j in range(0,l):
            Dx=np.linalg.solve(D,X[i]-X[j])
            M[k+j]= np.dot(Dx,X[i]-X[j])
   
        k+=l
    return M
```

Is there a way to speed up the function, i.e. not use two for loops, because it is taking too long to run.

As an example in the above I want the sizes of the inputs to be approximately: X is a 1000 times 3 numpy array, and D is a 3 times 3 numpy array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are several ways to do this.

One possible is to calculate only when j>i, which will only give half of matrix M (as M is symmetric, this could be fine).

I will list three ways to do that, take the one you like.

```
import numpy as np

import time


def matrix_0(X, D):
    # D1 = np.linalg.inv(D)
    n = len(X)
    M = np.zeros(n**2)
    k = 0 # set counter for indexing matrix
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            Dx = np.linalg.solve(D, X[i]-X[j])
            # Dx = np.inner(D1, X[i]-X[j])
            M[k+j]= np.dot(Dx, X[i]-X[j])
        k += n
    return M



def matrix_1(X, D):
    D1 = np.linalg.inv(D)
    n = len(X)
    M = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)]
    # set counter for indexing matrix
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            M[i][j] = np.matmul( X[i]-X[j], np.matmul(D1, X[i]-X[j]))
            # M[i][j] = np.matmul( X[i]-X[j], np.linalg.solve(D, X[i]-X[j]))
    return M


def matrix(X, D):
    D1 = np.linalg.inv(D)
    Z = [np.array(e) for e in X.tolist()]
    M = [list(map(lambda e: np.matmul(Z[i]-e, np.matmul(D1, Z[i]-e)), Z) ) for i in range(len(Z) ) ]
    return M
```

Test the running time

```
X = np.random.normal(0, 2, (1000, 3))
D = np.array([[3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5]])


start0 = time.time()
M0 = matrix_0(X, D)

end0 = time.time()
# print the difference between start
# and end time in milli. secs
print("The execution time of matrix_0(X, D):",  (end0-start0) * 10**3, "ms")



start1 = time.time()
M1 = matrix_1(X, D)

end1 = time.time()
# print the difference between start
# and end time in milli. secs
print("The execution time of matrix_1(X, D):", (end1-start1) * 10**3, "ms")



start = time.time()
M = matrix(X, D)

end = time.time()
# print the difference between start
# and end time in milli. secs
print("The execution time of matrix(X, D):", (end-start) * 10**3, "ms")
```

The results are as follows,

```
> The execution time of matrix_0(X, D): 7172.899484634399 ms
> The execution time of matrix_1(X, D): 1442.5835609436035 ms
> The execution time of matrix(X, D): 2639.496326446533 ms
```

Comment: is there no way to use meshgrid?